# Why don't I have a button in django rest framework for dynamically adding nested form data, if there should be one?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I ask for help

Take a look at the screenshot please, I can't understand why I can't add links dynamically

[Click 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAbqZ.jpg)

**This is the kind of Json format data you should get:**

```
values {
"firstname": "l",
"lastname": "m",
"links": [
{
  "linkname": "https://www.youtube.com/",
  "linkurl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
},
{
  "linkname": "https://www.youtube.com/",
  "linkurl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
}
]
}
```

And besides, even if all these existing fields are filled in (well, that is, those fields that are already in the django rest framework, namely, one array of **links** and the First Name along with the Last Name), an error is displayed:

> The .create() method does not support writable nested fields by default. Write an explicit .create() method for serializer schedule.serializers.WorkSuperSerializer, or set read_only=True on nested serializer fields.

I went through a lot of solutions to the problem, for example, I declared the **create()** method:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        links_data = validated_data.pop('links')
        worksuper = WorkSuper.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for link_data in links_data:
            Link.objects.create(worksuper=worksuper, **link_data)
        return worksuper
```

But it didn't fix the error(((((

**In general, here is my code:**

***Models.py:***

```
class WorkSuper(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=10, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=30, blank=True)
class Link(models.Model):
    links = models.ForeignKey(WorkSuper, related_name='links', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    linkname = models.CharField("linkname", max_length=100, blank=True)
    linkurl = models.CharField("linkurl", max_length=100, blank=True)
```

**Serializers.py:**

```
class WorkSuperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    links = LinkSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = WorkSuper
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'links')
        # depth = 1

        def create(self, validated_data):
            links_data = validated_data.pop('links')
            worksuper = WorkSuper.objects.create(**validated_data)
            for link_data in links_data:
                Link.objects.create(worksuper=worksuper, **link_data)
            return worksuper
        # def to_representation(self, instance):
        #     data = super().to_representation(instance)
        #     data['links']['links'] = instance.inner.link
        #     # return super().to_representation(instance)
        #     return data
```

**Views.py:**

```
class WorkSuperView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = WorkSuperSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = WorkSuper.objects.all()
       return queryset

   def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       queryset = self.get_queryset()
       serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
       data = serializer.data
       # return JsonResponse({'data': data})
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

I also want to tell you that it turns out like this json when filling out the form (screenshot below), that is, **links** are empty (((

[Click 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvssn.jpg)

I hope for help, because I haven't been able to figure it out for a long time.(((

Thank you in advance Please help

\I really can't handle it for a very, very long time, I've just reread everything.